# Using Javascript libraries with parcel leads to 'ReferenceError: XXX is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, parceljs

I am trying to use Parcel for a [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) presentation. Reveal.js uses a number of Javascript libraries, which are not module-aware.

The HTML file is

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.8.0/css/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.8.0/css/theme/white.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>Some code
                <pre><code data-trim data-noescape>
            (def lazy-fib
              (concat
               [0 1]
               <mark>((fn rfib [a b]</mark>
                    (lazy-cons (+ a b) (rfib b (+ a b)))) 0 1)))
                </code></pre>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/highlight.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a basic reveal.js slide with code highlighting. Adding code highlighting is relevant since we need to import two Javascript files.

Running with `parcel index.html` or `parcel build index.html` results in Javascript files that are wrapped with UMD. Unfortunately, that also means that I get reference errors:

- ReferenceError: hljs is not defined
- ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined

For just one module I could've used `parcel --global RevealJS` , but for two modules I don't have such an option.

I did not find an option to remove UMD wrapping for parcel, and I don't control the Javascript files to change them somehow.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: make sure your assets folder is relative to index.html

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - thanks for your comment. The assets are there where they should be. But wrapped in UMD/Require.JS form so they are not accessible to my inline script.

Comment: you are supposed to have only 1 entry file and in that file `import` other files, and Parcel will bundle them. in your code I do not see anything related to Parcel